получение ключа активации виндовс
купил ноут, на нем по умолчанию стояла винда 11 про, поставил себе вместо нее убнту сейчас решил все откатить, как получить ключ активации винды который был изначально? (я знаю, что я дурачек и надо было ставить убунту параллельно с виндой в разных разделах диска, раз уж просто поиграться захотело, но имеем что имеем)

А наклеек с серийным номером винды не было на ноуте? И в коробке с ноутом должны быть наклейки, если винда лицензионная. По-моему их несколько штук прилагается, как-раз чтобы не потерялись.

Может быть в UEFI, но есть нюансы.

поподробнее, пожалуйста, про UEFI


искать наклейку с ключом. 2. на некоторых ноутах ключ зашит в BIOS\UEFI и должен подхватываться при установке автоматически (если еще даже не пытались установить решив "сначала найду ключ", таки попробуйте поставить, мб повёзет). на будущее чтоб не рисковать имеющейся системой, возьмите себе за правило - ставить новую ОС только на отдельный накопитель(оставив старую на всякий случай)


Обычно если винда предустановлена то с обратной стороны ноута должна быть бирка с ключиком активации, по виду вот примерно такая.


на коробке есть наклейка со штрихкодом и надписью microsoft product key ID#(тут айди) и снизу штрих-код, это как-то может помочь и как ? таких наклеек как вы показали нет, к сожалению

Если как на картинке на жёлтеньком группы букв и цифр, то это как-раз ключ.

нет, только цифры, просто айдишник и всё

Есть практика что клеят эти наклейки в документацию к ноуту, либо прям на коробку от ноута, проверьте на этом всём, если нету  то лучше обратиться в магазин и уточнить, куда они приклеили этот ключ, либо же они где то в доках его указали, человеческий фактор тут играет роль.
